# How to express that a schema.org/Restaurant is located in a given Wikidata geographical entity?

Tags: rdf, wikidata, wikivoyage

I created this RDF restaurant description...

```
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID='Nb925d432-69b1-42e0-8063-d914e3504dde'>
<rdf:type rdf:resource='http://schema.org/Restaurant'/>
<schema:name>Chez Mel</schema:name>
<schema:address>63-65 rue Saint-Vulfran</schema:address>
<schema:telephone>+33 3 22 19 48 64</schema:telephone>
<schema:description>Hearty and family-friendly restaurant.</schema:description>
</rdf:Description>
```

... by extracting info from [the "Abbeville" Wikivoyage article](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Abbeville), which itself points to [the "Abbeville" Wikidata item](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q28520).

How can I update the code above to indicate that this restaurant is in that Wikidata geographical entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create another entity that represents Abbeville, set it as [`schema:location`](http://schema.org/location) (or maybe [`schema:containedIn`](http://schema.org/containedIn)?) of the restaurant and then use [`schema:sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) to link to that Wikidata URI:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID='Nb925d432-69b1-42e0-8063-d914e3504dde'>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://schema.org/Restaurant'/>
    <schema:name>Chez Mel</schema:name>
    <schema:address>63-65 rue Saint-Vulfran</schema:address>
    <schema:telephone>+33 3 22 19 48 64</schema:telephone>
    <schema:description>Hearty and family-friendly restaurant.</schema:description>
    <schema:location>
        <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID='NsomeotherGUID'>
            <rdf:type rdf:resource='http://schema.org/City'/>
            <schema:sameAs rdf:resource='https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q28520'/>
        </rdf:Description>
    </schema:location>
</rdf:Description>
```